# How can I send a query to database after the request is handled?

Tags: asynchronous, python-3.x, tornado

I have an application that does the following:

- After the app receives a get request, it reads the client's cookies
  for identification.
- It stores the identification information in Postgresql DB
- And it sends the appropriate response and finishes the handling
  process.

But in this way the client is also waiting for me to store the data in PSQL. I don'
t want this what I want is:

- After the app receives a get request, it reads the client's cookies
  for identification.
- It sends the appropriate response and finishes the handling process.
- It stores the identification information in Postgresql DB.

In the second part storing process is happening after the client has received his response so he won't have to wait for it. I've searched for a solution but haven't found anything thus far. I believe I'm searching with wrong keywords because, I believe this is a common problem.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a callback to the ioloop.  Via some code like this:

```
from tornado import ioloop

def somefuction(*args):
   # call the DB

...
...  now in your get() or post() handler
...

io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
io_loop.add_callback(partial(somefunction, arg, arg2))

... rest of your handler ...
self.finish()
```

This will get called after the response is returned to the user on the next iteration through the event handler to call your DB processor `somefunction`.

Comment: Perfect answer I was considering using the database calls after self.finish() but this is more elegant

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to wait for Postgres to respond you could try

1) An [async postgres driver](https://github.com/FSX/momoko)

2) Put the DB jobs on a queue and let the queue handle the DB write. Try [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)

Remember because you return to the user before you write to the DB you have to think about how to handle write errors

Comment: I am using momoko as async postgres driver

The information I'm storing is like user-id, user-agent, remote-ip etc. so it's not vital. I decided to send queries after finishing the response with self.finish()